# Request with Array of Objects (complextype) in Android using KSOAP

Tags: android, request, ksoap

I have this webservice:

```
<message name="getListOB3Request">
<part name="user" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="pass" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="server" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="tableName" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="fields" type="tns:ArrayOfFieldOB"/>
<part name="sql" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

Array of FieldOB is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfFieldOB">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
<xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="FieldOB[]"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and FieldOB is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="FieldOB">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="St_field" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

i have a OBField class that implement kvmSerializable

```
public class OBField implements Serializable, KvmSerializable
{
  ...
}
```

and a ArrayOBField class that implement kvmSerializable

```
public class OBArrayListSerializable extends ArrayList<OBField> implements Serializable, KvmSerializable
{
  ....
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                propertyInfo.name = "ArrayOfFieldOB";
                propertyInfo.type = new OBField().getClass();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

the webservice call:

```
  envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "fields", new OBArrayListSerializable().getClass());

  HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_GENERAL+url);

  try
   {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_GENERAL+metodo, envelope);
        SoapObject response (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
   }
```

this is my request (envelope.bodyOut)

```
getListOB3{user=myUser; pass=myPass; 
    server=http://localhost/test; 
    tableName=BusinessPartner; 
    fields=[com.androidTest.ws.OBField@44e8c988, com.androidTest.ws.OBField@44e8ca20]; 
    sql=; }
```

the problem has in "fields" that is an array of OBField.

seems that the web service does not receive correctly the "fields"

thanks

Comment: did you find any work around